# Ballast wiring for 4 tube lights?

Tags: ballast

I have 347V Ballast wired. See attached the existing wiring and the one specified on the Ballast itself.
Experienced & Experts, please comment: Would it still work?

For my knowledge,

1. Are the Yellow wires coming out of the Ballast are internally jumpered/bridged?
2. Are 2 Blue wires coming out of the Ballast are internally jumpered/bridged?
3. Are 2 Red wires wires coming out of the Ballast are internally jumpered/bridged?
4. Does it make any difference if one end of 2 Tube lights are connected to one Yellow wire coming out of Ballast and the other end of the lights go to one Blue & one Red wire coming out of Ballast?

enter image description here
Fusion Ballast for 4 lights

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the keyboard warriors saying "retrofit direct-wire LED tubes", please link one that accepts 347V. Needs to be c/UL or CSA listed.

> Are the Yellow wires coming out of the Ballast are internally jumpered/bridged?

Maybe. Difficult to say what they're doing internally without a teardown.

> Are 2 Blue wires coming out of the Ballast are internally jumpered/bridged?

No.  That's not compatible with how fluorescent lights work.  You're thinking both tubes are wired in parallel, but that only works for constant-voltage devices.  Fluorescents and LEDs are not such things, and neither was the incandescent until Thomas Edison figured out how to make it so.

> Are 2 Red wires wires coming out of the Ballast are internally jumpered/bridged?

No.

> Does it make any difference if one end of 2 Tube lights are connected to one Yellow wire coming out of Ballast and the other end of the lights go to one Blue & one Red wire coming out of Ballast?

Maybe. But it doesn't benefit you *in any way whatsoever* to purposefully miswire the ballast.  Your proposed wiring diagram does not correspond to the ballast wiring diagram.  Follow the instructions and labeling.

The wiring is designed not only to be easy for you, but also to be easy for the next person to service the fixture.  Consistency is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the diagram on the new ballast.

Period.

The way it was becomes irrelevant when you change the ballast. Not following the instructions of the new ballast is both a code violation and a failure of common sense. Don't be "creative" or "lazy" about it. Follow the diagram of the new ballast.

Comment: Changed the wiring according to the one shown on the Ballast and all 4 lights are working. 
Thank you so much everyone for your comments and suggestions.